# Let $F$ be a field and $R=F \oplus F$. Are the submodules $F \oplus 0$ and $0 \oplus F$ isomorphic as $F$ modules? What about as $R$ modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $R=F \oplus F$. Are the submodules $F \oplus 0$ and $0 \oplus F$ isomorphic as $F$ modules? What about as $R$ modules?

I was thinking that they would be isomorphic as both $F$ modules and $R$ modules, provided you find the correct isomorphism. Is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: "$F$-module" means vector space. We have a very nice and easy test for determining when two vector spaces over $F$ are isomorphic, so that should be straightforward.

Comment: (Well, technically, if you find *any* isomorphism, then that proves they are isomorphic; so presumably, you did not mean to ask "if there is an isomorphism between them, does it follow they are isomorphic?" Rather, you mean to ask "Does there exist an isomorphism between them?")

Comment: Suppose $f\colon (F\oplus 0)\to (0\oplus F)$ is an $R$-module homomorphism. For each $x\in F$, there is a unique $g(x)\in F$ such that $f(x,0) = (0,g(x))$.  Then for all $(a,b)\in R$, $f(ax,0) = f((a,b)(x,0)) = (a,b)f(x,0) = (a,b)(0,g(x)) = (0,bg(x))$, so $g(ax)=bg(x)$. But this must hold for all $b\in R$, which is likely to cause some issues...

Comment: yeah, i just meant exhibiting an explicit isomorphism would be the way to go in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, $M_1 = F \oplus 0$ and $M_2 = 0 \oplus F$ are not isomorhic  $R$-modules, as their annihilators in $R$ namely $0 \oplus F$ and $F \oplus 0$ are different.

Comment: the fact that their annihilators are isomorphic doesn't matter?

Comment: @MichaelVaughan: No it doesn't matter. If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are isomorphic and $f\colon M_1\to M_2$ is a module homomorphism, then $a\in \mathrm{ann}(M_1)\iff am=0\text{ for all }m\iff f(am)=0\text{ for all }m$. This is equivalent to  $af(m)=0\text{ for all }m$, and since $f$ is onto, this occurs if and only if  $an=0\text{ for all } n$, which is equivalent to $a\in\mathrm{ann}(M_2)$.

So the annihilators have to be *identical*, not just isomorphic.

Comment: So the reason that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not isomorphic as $R$-modules is that any the multiplication that is preserved by the isomorphism does not extend to the way that $R$ acts on $M_2$, is this correct thinking?

Comment: They are not isomorphic as $R$-modules because the action of $R$ on each of them is essentially different, and the isomorphism must preserve the action. An isomorphism of modules means that the modules are "really the same", but you are somehow calling their elements differently. But the ring acts on the object, no the name, so the action has to be exactly the same action. Here, it just isn't the same action, as evidenced by the annihilators.